# multi key tuple to map a multi value tuple in Lua

Tags: lua

Is there a lib in Lua that supports a map from a tuple to a tuple? I have a key {a,b,c} to map to a value {c,d,e}
There are libs such as, http://lua-users.org/wiki/MultipleKeyIndexing for multikey but not where the value is a tuple.

Comment: Convert your tuple to a string `tostring(a)..";"..tostring(b)..";"..tostring(c)` and use this string as index.

Comment: I don't see any limitation on the type(s) of the values in the linked library.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to use Egor's suggestion for making a key through string concatenation. Make your own simple insert and get methods for a table, t.

```
local a, b, c = 10, 20, 30
local d, e, f = 100, 200, 300

local t = {}
t.key = function (k)
  local key = ""
  for _,v in ipairs(k) do
     key = key .. tostring(v) .. ";"
   end
   return key
end
t.set = function (k, v)
  local key = t.key(k)
  t[key] = v
end
t.get = function (k)
  local key = t.key(k)
  return t[key]
end

t.set ({a, b, c}, {d, e, f})           -- using variables
t.set ({40, 50, 60}, {400, 500, 600})  -- using constants

local w = t.get ({a, b, c})               -- using variables
local x = t.get ({40, 50, 60})            -- using constants

print(w[1], w[2], w[3])                   -- 100    200    300
print(x[1], x[2], x[3])                   -- 400    500    600
```

Comment: Your "insert" is very different than `table.insert`. Please use "set" as the complement to "get".